# I have problem about second diagonal in decreasing order

Tags: c

Input an array of n x n (n is even). Sort the 1st diagonal in increasing order and the 2nd
diagonal in decreasing order. 1st diagonal starts with element [0,0], 2nd diagonal starts with
elements [n-1,0]

[btw i have already found my fault. and it it give the right results. so, i will give my code below]

```
void sortDiagonals (int n, int arr[100][100])
{
    '//1st diagonal in increasing order
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][i] > arr[j][j])
            {
                int temp = arr[j][j];
                arr[j][j] = arr[i][i];
                arr[i][i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    '//2nd diagonal in decreasing order
    for (int i = n - 1, j = 0; i > 0, j < n - 1; i--, j++)
    {
        for (int a = i - 1, b = j + 1; a >= 0, b <= n - 1 ; a--, b++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] > arr[a][b]) 
            {
                int temp = arr[i][j];
                arr[i][j] = arr[a][b];
                arr[a][b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When `i == n-1` then `j = i + 1` accesses the array out of bounds. You should avoid writing obscure for loops since they almost always create a lot of bugs. Try to use the `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` form when possible and instead add offsets etc to the indexes inside the loop body.

Comment: Given the O(N^2) sorting algorithm you are using, note that you could use just *one* nested loop to sort both diagonals. Consider that at row `i`, the diagonal element is at column `i`, while the antidiagonal is at `n - 1 - i` and note that `i` should stop *before* `n - 1`.

Comment: @Lundin thankyou. But i have no idea to solve this problem, i already try 'for(int i=0; i<n; i++)' form for my idea but i can not show the right result for 2nd diagonals. Do you have any suggest???

Comment: The posted code has another problem: https://godbolt.org/z/a8GhaM4KM because `i > 0, j >= n - 1 ` doesn't do what you might think. Please read about the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

> [But i have no idea to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76512669/i-have-problem-about-second-diagonal-in-decreasing-order/76517178#comment134906604_76512669)

Save time, enable all warnings.

Example

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion ...
../my_gets.c: In function 'sortDiagonals':
../my_gets.c:17:37: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   17 |     for (int i = n - 1, j = 0; i > 0, j < n - 1; i--, j++)
      |                                     ^
../my_gets.c:19:46: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   19 |         for (int a = i - 1, b = j + 1; a >= 0, b <= n - 1 ; a--, b++)
      |                                              ^
```